# How can you determine if your Facebook Application is being accessed on a User Profile or Facebook Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In this article:

http://facebookappcode.wordpress.com/2010/01/29/tab-application/

It states:

**The UID of the tab owner is provided to your application with the fb_sig_profile_user parameter**

A Facebook owner can be an admin of multiple pages, so if fb_sig_profile_user represents
the Admin there is no way to tell which Facebook Page the applications is installed at.

If fb_sig_profile_user returns ID of Facebook Page when the application is being accessed from a Facebook Page, then it would be straight forward to figure out that the access is coming from a Facebook Page.

fb_sig_profile_user seems to be imply that it is the ID of a user.

Any help on this would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Facebook apps can no longer be installed on a User Profile page, so you can be sure that your app is being accessed from a fan page.  The fan page ID should be passed in the fb_sig parameter.  I've now switched to OAuth for Canvas 2.0, so I'm getting a signed_request which contains the page id.  When I was using the old fb_sig parameter, I was also getting the page id, but I can't remember exactly what the parameter name was.

Comment: Here is how my app works now:  a Facebook users authorizes the application, they can then add the applications to one or many Facebook Pages that they administer by clicking the "Add to my Page" link when they visit the apps wall page.  I can't figure out how to tell which Facebook Page the application requests are coming from at this time.